# git-svn fetch fails on file whose size > LONG_MAX

Tags: perl, git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to use git-svn to migrate from subversion.

right now I am blocked by the failure of

```
$ git svn fetch
```

fails on line 900 of Git.pm (from the git-svn package)

```
...
    my $read = read($in, $blob, $bytesToReadd);
```

in the sub called cat_blob()
The problem is that the file is 2567089913 bytes, and when git-svn gets to 2147484672 it chokes with a message "Offset outside of string".
cat_blob tries to hold the entire file in a variable before writing it to disk.

I tried moving the writing of the file from the end of the sub to inside the read loop,

(here is what my modified code looks like)

```
890         my $size = $1;
891 
892         my $blob;
893         my $bytesRead = 0;
894 
895         while (1) {
896                 my $bytesLeft = $size - $bytesRead;
897                 last unless $bytesLeft;
898 
899                 my $bytesToRead = $bytesLeft < 1024 ? $bytesLeft : 1024;
900                 print $size, " ", $bytesLeft, " ", $bytesRead, "\n";
901                 my $read = read($in, $blob, $bytesToReadd);
902                 unless (defined($read)) {
903                         $self->_close_cat_blob();
904                         throw Error::Simple("in pipe went bad");
905                 unless (print $fh $blob) {
906                         $self->_close_cat_blob();
907                         throw Error::Simple("couldn't write to passed in filehandle");
908         }
909 
910                 }
911 
912                 $bytesRead += $read;
913         }
```

but now I get a new error:

```
Checksum mismatch: root/Instruments/MY_DIR/MASSIVE_FILE.exe bca43a9cb6c3b7fdb76c460781eb410a34b6b9ec
expected: 52daf59b450b82a541e782dbfb803a32
     got: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

I'm not a perl guy.  Does perl put extra crap onto the print statement there? 
Any ideas how I can pass the checksum?

Comment: `$\ ` is appended to what `print` prints, but it's the empty string by default and if it wasn't empty, it would have created bad files even before your change.

Comment: I was able to get a patch accepted to fix this in the official git tree. This is still a problem in the wild, but it should be fixed in git 1.8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error becomes apparent when you fix the indenting.

```
890         my $size = $1;
891 
892         my $blob;
893         my $bytesRead = 0;
894 
895         while (1) {
896                 my $bytesLeft = $size - $bytesRead;
897                 last unless $bytesLeft;
898 
899                 my $bytesToRead = $bytesLeft < 1024 ? $bytesLeft : 1024;
900                 print $size, " ", $bytesLeft, " ", $bytesRead, "\n";
901                 my $read = read($in, $blob, $bytesToReadd);
902      --->       unless (defined($read)) {
903                     $self->_close_cat_blob();
904                     throw Error::Simple("in pipe went bad");
905      --->           unless (print $fh $blob) {
906                         $self->_close_cat_blob();
907                         throw Error::Simple("couldn't write to passed in filehandle");
908                     }
909 
910                 }
911 
912                 $bytesRead += $read;
913         }
```

The `print` is never reached. Just move 905-909 to 912.

Oh and you mispelled `$bytesToRead` as `$bytesToReadd` in line 901. Didn't the compiler pick that up?

You should use a block size larger than 1024. 64*1024 would be much faster.

Comment: Good eye! Punished by my own sloppiness. I suspect speed is why the original code buffers the entire file before writing to disk. There has to be a happy medium between trying to buffer 2 GiB, and writing every kilobyte, but the latter should never fail, block and buffer sizes notwithstanding

Comment: @Joshua Clayton, After your edit, my answer no longer showed the problem! I had to revert it.

Comment: It was my understanding that the answer to a question (if it includes code) is preferred to be fixed (i.e. working) code. Thanks for your help. I am testing a version that includes an inner variable to flush the blob less frequently. I'll post later if it improves performance over the simpler code.

Comment: You can add working code if you want, but not at the cost of removing the explanation.